# Text filtering using SED or AWK

Tags: text-processing

My document has the following aspect:

```
Text1
\begin{code}
code1
\end{code}
Text2
\begin{code}
  -- comment1
  code1A
\end{code}
Text3

\begin{code}
  -- comment2
  code1B
\end{code}
Text4

\begin{code}
codeB
\end{code}
Text 5
```

The output that I'm looking for is something like this:

```
code1

  -- comment1
  code1A

  -- comment2
  code1B

codeB
```

Comment: Are you processing LaTeX files?

Comment: Well, sort of. I have literate Agda files.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: An edit to the question has since made this solution obsolete.

---

Since you simply want to filter specific lines to the output, `grep` can do the job.

```
$ grep -v -e "T[0-9]" -e '^\\begin{code}$' -e '^\\end{code}$' file.txt
code1
  -- comment1
  code1A
  -- comment2
  code1B
codeB
```

Comment: It's not just T1 or T2, they are complete text including spaces, newlines... normal text.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a desired output without specifying the rules / logics to apply for it to be obtained doesn't really help solving your problem. Someone could just echo / print the output without relation to the input. Assuming you want the lines between `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}` excluding either, try

```
sed -n '/\\begin/,/\\end/ {/{code}/!p}' file
code1
  -- comment1
  code1A
  -- comment2
  code1B
codeB
```

If you need the empty lines, append `/^ *$/p` to the `sed` script.

**EDIT:** Like so:

```
$ sed -n '/\\begin/,/\\end/ {/{code}/!p}; /^ *$/p' file
code1
  -- comment1
  code1A

  -- comment2
  code1B

codeB
```

Comment: Yes, I need the empty lines, how would it be, I tried "append ...", it doesn't work.

Comment: It does. I tested. WHAT did you append? In WHICH WAY doesn't it work?

Comment: `sed -n '/\\begin/,/\\end/ {/{code}/!/^ *$/p}' $< > $@`.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: ``$ sed -n '/\\begin/,/\\end/ {/{code}/!p}; /^ *p' file``` I got this
sed: 1: "/\\begin/,/\\end/ {/{co ...": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: Using gsed I got this: ```gsed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated address rege```